# is git-upload-pack necessary?

Tags: git, android

I'm getting the following error when trying to pull from a git repository:

```
sh: git-upload-pack: not found
```

I've seen many discussions about it and all of them suggest setting some path so that
the binary git-upload-pack can be found.  However, I'm trying to pull from a git repository on my android (phone) which has a barely functional git client.

Performing the following on my android returns nothing:

```
which git-upload-pack
```

Can't git do without git-upload-pack on a remote repo?

Comment: I was able to mount the android phone's storage on my windows machine using WebDav and then pull from the  android repo  as if it was a local folder.

Answer (score 1):

You do need it as it is part of git-fetch pack logic.